# Transpiled .js files in repo

Tags: angular, sublimetext3, angular-universal

I'm using [this](https://github.com/ng-seed/universal/issues) repo to work on a project, and everything is working fine. I'm using Sublime Text as my editor and due to a some combination of keys that I don't know now, I caused the editor to start showing transpiled .js files for EVERY typescript file. It has cluttered my my Git client and I can't figure out the key combination to reverse the effects of this. Would be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Found the culprit! I had accidentally pressed cmd + B, which had compiled the files in Sublime. Since they were only intermediate states between actual compiled files there was no harm in getting rid of them.